# Jmeter - illegal use of undefined variable using Calendar

Tags: java, calendar, jmeter

I need to calculate some dates in jmeter, so I created a BeanShell Pre Processor in my test structure:

1. Thread Group

   - Cache Manager
   - Cookie Manager
   - HTTP Header
   - HTTP Manager
   - IF controller (if the user could login)
   - BeanShell Pre Processor

And my code it's like:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

try {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat df= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssX");
    long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    long endTime = Long.parseLong(vars.get("dateMiliseconds")); 
    randomStartDate = df.format(startTime + (long)(Math.random()*(endTime-startTime)));
    randomEndDate = randomTime1 + (long)(Math.random()*(endTime - randomTime1)+86400000);
    log.warn("startDate: "+randomStartDate+ " endDate: "+randomEndDate);
    vars.put("RandomStartDate", randomStartDate);
    vars.put("RandomEndDate", randomEndDate); 
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.warn("The error is: "+e);
    throw e;
}
```

However when I ran the test Jmeter error says:

> ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: 
>   `import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; import java.util.Calendar;  try{    Calendar ca . . .  :` illegal use of undefined variable, class, or 'void' literal
>
> WARN  - jmeter.modifiers.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: 
>   `import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; import java.util.Calendar;  try{    Calendar ca . . .`: illegal use of undefined variable, class, or 'void' literal

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `randomTime1` is not defined anywhere, it need to have some value.

Also it is better to use `public final void warn(String message, Throwable throwable)` method - this way you will be able to see the full stacktrace in jmeter.log file.

And finally, for performance perspective it's better to use either [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time), [__longSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum) and [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) functions combination or consider moving to [JSR223 PreProcessor and groovy language](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) if you want to stick to scripting

Comment: Great. I forgot to define the variable. Now I have an error using '-' operator so I'll follow your advise about jmeter functions. Thanks